# Angularfire2 add a new user to the database

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I used the following login method:

```
login() {
  this.auth.login();
this.authService.login().subscribe(() => {
  if (this.authService.isLoggedIn) {
      console.log("ADDING THE USER..");
      // Add a new user to the users table
      this.af.child("users").child(this.authService.userData.uid).set({
          provider: this.authService.userData.provider,
            name: this.getName(this.authService.userData)
      });
    // Redirect the user
    this.router.navigate(['/panel']);
  }
});
```

}

Which almost same as the method in the documentation: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing

When I run my app, I get the following error:

```
Property 'child' does not exist on type 'AngularFire'.
```

and the user is not added. What's wrong?

All I need is to add a new object to my Firebase database.
The following works, but I need the structure as shown above:

```
this.users = this.af.database.list('/users');
this.users.push("TEST");
```

So, How I can add a new user object into my database using the same structure in https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing? and why I can't run my code if it's same as documented?

**Update**

My new code:

```
this.af.database.object('/users/${this.authService.userData.uid}').set({
              provider: this.authService.userData.provider,
                name: this.getName(this.authService.userData)
          });
```

- No user inserted (my firebase database is empty)

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/2-retrieving-data-as-objects.md#api-summary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `object()`; child() doens't exist:

```
this.af.database.object(`users/${this.authService.userData.uid}`).set({...})
```

Comment: Cool one, thanks. but you forgot to add `.database` after the `.af`. Anyway, I have no idea why but nothing is added to my database. Updated my code

Comment: Are you getting an error? Are your security rules ok?

Comment: I get no error. My rulese are: `{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true"
  }
}` In my firebase database console I see only `null`

Comment: Well there is problem with what's inside my `set` but  no error at all. anywayw I got it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This one is a shorter version.

```
import { AngularFireDatabase } from "angularfire2";

...

constructor(private afd: AngularFireDatabase) {}

...

this.afd.object(`users/${this.authService.userData.uid}`).set({...});
```